# Trying to understand a two-tailed paired t-test

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

I have two data sets $M$ and $N$ that are equally large. They have different averages and medians and I want to prove that, with 5% significance, the values don't differ solely out of chance.

I'm trying to understand what the **two-tailed paired t-test** really tells me. I've performed such a test using Google Sheets built-in function TTEST() and it returns the value 0.03. Does this mean that it's a 3% chance that the values differed as they did solely out of chance and that I've successfully proved (at a 5% significance level) that they in fact differ?

Comment: Yes. This is the so-called $p$-value. And if you get $0.03<0.05$ then the hypothesis that means are equal should be rejected at 5% significance level since there is only 3% of chances that data sets with the same means show given difference of avarages.

Comment: That is an excellent answer, thank you so much. If you want to post it as a separate answer I'll gladly mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is the so-called $p$-value. And if you get $0.03<0.05$ then the hypothesis that the means are equal should be rejected at $5\%$ significance level since there is only $3\%$ of chances that data sets with the same means show such difference of averages.